# How to render components in react-router-dom with bundle.js file?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've created a web-app and using react-router-dom for navigations in the app. Everything works fine when I start the app using webpack-dev-server and now its time to deploy this app on my server so I've created a bundle file of this app using webpack command but react-router-dom is not rendering any component with bundle.js file either I add switch or not.

One more thing when I click on URL or refresh the page I get an error "webpage not found" even in webpack-dev-server. I want my application to work with urls as well not just with Link and Push. Here is my code

```
import {        
    Router,
    Route,
    Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import history from "./config/History";

import store from "./store";

const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/create/questions" component={CreateQuestion} />
                    <Route path="/create/quiz" component={CreateQuiz} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(router, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Webpack dev server is as the name suggests for development purposes... In production, you need to put together a simple server (i.e. an express server...)

Comment: Yeah I know dev server is used for development purposes. I had created another web-app using react, redux, and react-router a year ago. Unfortunately, I lost my code but I'm pretty sure that I was not using any server on the production level I still have that bundle file on my server that is handling the whole app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed this issue using HashRouter. There are some security issues with Router so you have to run it on a server e.g express server if you want to use that.

Here is my updated code. For history i'm using CreateHashHistory function from history.

```
import {
    HashRouter,
    Route,
    Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

<Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter history={history}>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Route exact  path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route exact  path="/create/questions" component={CreateQuestion} />
                <Route exact  path="/create/quiz" component={CreateQuiz} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
</Provider>
```